# Vim find and replace with filename as variable

Tags: substitute, search-replace

Is it possible to use vim *find and replace* to replace a variable with the current filename? for example, fancyFileName.txt contains

```
this is the VARIABLE to replace in this fancyFileName.txt
```

and I am trying to use something like `:%s/VARIABLE/expand(%)/` to get

```
this is the fancyFileName.txt to replace in this fancyFileName.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in other answers, `:help sub-replace-special`, and `:help \=`, you can use any expression as the replacement text like so:

```
:%substitute/\<VARIABLE\>/\=expression/g
```

In your case:

```
:%substitute/\<VARIABLE\>/\=expand('%')/g
```

Comment: I check this as the answer because it is easier to write (at least for me). However I spent some time with `help \=`, which didn't help, until I realized the explanation is in the answer by Christian. It might be word pointing to it more clearly in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @manolius great feedback, thanks. Is the new version better?

Comment: Yes! much appreciated for all the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have defined `VARIABLE` as a global Vim Script variable like this:

```
:let g:VARIABLE='fanceFileName.txt'
```

you can then use:

```
%s/\<VARIABLE\>/\=get(g:, submatch(0), '')/g
```

This uses the special atom `\=` to evaluate the following as a VimScript expression using `get(g:, 'VARIABLE', '')` to access the variable from the global dictionary `:g`

See also [:h sub-replace-special](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)